# Converting Object[] array to List in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, primefaces

on a primefaces 3.5 form I created with a datatable the rowKey value is not being returned as a List, therefore I am getting the following error:

```
JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report

JBWEB000068: message For input string: "foreignPartyId"

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: For input string: "foreignPartyId"
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foreignPartyId"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:407)
    javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:199)
...
```

I know the reason is because I am trying to populate the datatable with values from an Object[] array, rather than a List. The Object[] array is actually values from **getResultList()** using the **createNativeQuery** method to query an Oracle database.

My question is: How do I convert the values in the Object[] array into a List so that the datatable is populated?

I have tried using the Arrays.toList() method, and then iterating through that adding the values to a list, but I understand that that simply returns a fixed size list of the backed array. It does not return a List of values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My apologies if I have not provided enough detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

Try with ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
```

and then add whatever element you want to the list using

```
list.add(newItem)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am wondering if instead of Arrays.**toList** you meant Arrays.**asList**? I tried using Arrays.asList but am still getting the error. Can you clarify? Thanks again!!  :-)

Comment: It is "asList()", my bad: thanks for noticing the error. Are you sure that Object[] is representing the query result and not a single row returned by the query? If so then it is more trivial that you cannot add elements to the object array as it would mean trying to change the table data.

Comment: Good question. In fact, you have me re-thinking my query. This particular query would likely just return a single row. So, in fact I am wondering if I should using getSingleResult() instead of getResultList(). Either way, I guess I still have to figure out how to take returned resultset and populate the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

The `getResultList` method do return a `List<Object[]>` if you are for example querying multiple entities and the result cannot be mapped automatically onto an existing entity class.

To avoid this you may consider a constructor expression in your JPA query like this:

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
  .createQuery("SELECT NEW my.Foo(a.id, b.somethingelse) FROM --- ");
```

The `getResultList()` method now will return a `List<Foo>` and you do not run into the problem that you have mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you expand on the "my.Foo" part of the constructor expression in your JPA query example? I am not sure how to translate that to fit my situation. Thanks.

Comment: 'Foo' is just a dummy name here for some kind of data transfer object. Just create a POJO which is containing all the fields that you want to display in the datatable